# No able to export dump file from oracle DB

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, relational-database

I spent all day long to create dump of my oracle DB and tracking the possible solutions found online but unfortunately no one did worked for me, I am using this script :

```
 expdp user/password@databaseName DIRECTORY=orcl_full DUMPFILE=orclfull.dmp LOGFILE=full_exp.log FULL=YES;
```

I have no idea, why I am getting this error.

```
UDE-12504: operation generated ORACLE error 12504
ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA
```

**tnsname.ora**

```
ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myhost01)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl.tnt.dev)
    )
  )
```

**listener.ora**

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = orcl.tnt.dev)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1)
      (SID_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =myhost01)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

Please have a look I am looking for solution desperately.

Comment: @philipxy I think I have asked an appropriate question with appropriate amount of information, what else do you want me to add in here, Are you expecting me to design the question to look pretty. I am sorry, I just want to share knowledge that's the only moto I have.

Comment: Maybe [ORA-12541: TNS:no listener using EXPDP](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21621/ora-12541-tnsno-listener-using-expdp)?

Answer (score 0):

In the listener.ora you are using sid and in the tnsnames.ora, service_name is used. I guess this is causing the issue.
Register service_name for the database (or)enter code here use sid in the tnsnames.ora

```
ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myhost01)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SID = orcl)
    )
  )
```

Comment: I think that is not the problem, I go the solution through this video.           http://www.rebellionrider.com/oracle-data-pump-impdp-expdp/data-pump-expdp-how-to-export-full-database.htm#.WCwCrcnks3k